# React Router - path with regular expression for query string in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My application paths are defined as follows

```
domain_url/mtr/1234?type=c
domain_url/mtr/1234?type=sm
domain_url/mtr/1234?type=smd
```

I am handling the routing as follows. This one is working fine

```
<Route path='/mtr/:id' element={<Component />} />
```

Now my requirement is I have to enable only the following path

```
domain_url/mtr/1234?type=c
```

Currently, we are not exposing the other two paths.

I tried the route path as follows

```
<Route path='/mtr/:id?type=c' element={<Component />} />
```

I am getting `No routes matched location "/mtr/1234?type=c"` error.

I'm using `react-router@4`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Route>` element should capture the path without the query parameter

i.e. :

```
<Route path='/mtr/:id' element={<Component />} />
```

The link to the route can have the query param

```
<Link to="/mtr/12345?type=c">Netflix</Link>
```

the component handling the the specific route (in this case `<Component/>` ) can access this query parameer

```
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
...
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
searchParams.get("type")
```

and do the required filtering / logic required

see working example here: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-r-router-qparams-7qjjnh?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Route paths only care about the ***path*** part of a URL, the queryString is ignored for route path matching. You'll just need to validate the `queryString` values in the component and handle accordingly.

Example:

Since you originally tagged `react-router@4`

```
<Route path='/mtr/:id' component={Component} />
```

```
const Component = ({ history, location }) => {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const type = searchParams.get("type");
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== "c") {
      history.back();
    }
  }, [history, type]);

  ...
};
```

The `Route` component is using `react-router@6` syntax/API though, so just in case you are using v6.

```
<Route path='/mtr/:id' element={<Component />} />
```

```
import { useNavigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Component = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const type = searchParams.get("type");
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== "c") {
      navigate(-1);
    }
  }, [navigate, type]);

  ...
};
```